# CakePHP access restricted files after authentication

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, file-upload, acl

I have an ACL controlled application that uses the [Media plugin](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin) to upload files to `/app/webroot/media`.  When a file is uploaded, the dirname, basename and file name are written to the database.

I'm looking for a way to restrict access to `/app/webroot/media`, allowing users to only view the files associated with their user id after they have signed in.  Currently, users can access other user's files which is not at all ideal. Is there a best practice for this as far as CakePHP is concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any file under webroot will be publicly accessible if the user knows the url. Store your files in a folder outside webroot and then render them through a controller action using [CakeResponse::file()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file). This way you can controller access to the action as required.

Comment: Thanks ADmad, that's actually what I'm doing at the moment.  Is it possible to have images render automatically within a view by sending responses via CakeResponse?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you are rendering a file using CakeResponse::file() you don't need any view.

Comment: I have a view and download button for both CakeResponse::file() and CakeResponse::download() actions.  What I'd like is to display a thumbnail to the user beside the buttons if the file is an image.

Comment: I actually just wound up putting the call to action within an iframe src field :)

Comment: Why iframe? If you are rendering an image just put the action url as img tag source.